# why is there this extra section in my code?

Tags: html, css

checkout this codepen[https://codepen.io/pen/]

Whenever I enter an element like h1 or p, this extra space comes into the design. If I remove the h1 in #second, this space is removed. I donot know why it is there.
thanks.

my code:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

#container {
  width: 400px;
  background-color: gray;
  height: 800px;
  margin: 20px auto;
  box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #BEBEBE;
}

#first {
  height: 250px;
  background-image: url(https://wallpapercave.com/wp/KLaNOxd.jpg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#second {
  background-color: white;
  height: 530px;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="first">
    </div>
    <div id="second">
      <div class="today">
        <h1>bgbjbgjrgjn</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tommorow"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

[image: code image]

Comment: your codepen link is broken

Comment: Open your browsers development console and pick the element. Then examine its layout rules. You will find what causes it yourself.

Comment: maybe just maybe its the gray background from the container but just maybe ;)

Comment: Soory. Here's the link. [link](https://codepen.io/bhanu_2000/pen/jXWOEV)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `h1` and `p` elements have a default margin applied to them, which causes a space.

```
h1 {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Setting the `margin: 0` to your `h1` element will resolve your issue. I also suggest you make a class and apply this style to your class so you're not affecting all `h1` tags on your page.

See working example below:

```html
<style>
  * {
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  #container {
    width: 400px;
    background-color: gray;
    height: 800px;
    margin: 20px auto;
    box-shadow: 5px 5px 15px #BEBEBE;
  }
  
  #first {
    height: 250px;
    background-image: url(https://wallpapercave.com/wp/KLaNOxd.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
    border: 2px solid red;
  }
  
  #second {
    background-color: white;
    height: 530px;
  }
  
  .no-margin { /* remove the margin */
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div id="first">
    </div>
    <div id="second">
      <div class="today">
        <h1 class="no-margin">bgbjbgjrgjn</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="tommorow"></div>
         
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks. Just a small doubt, the default margin should shift the `h1` down, why does it shifts the whole `div` down?

Comment: @bhanu_2000, default margin applying on top, right, bottom, and left.

Answer (score 1):

This is because of `default margin` applying on `<h1>` tag. So please add this CSS.

```
h1 {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
 }
```

**Note:** As `<h1>` tag gets a `default margin` of bootstraps or from others Style.

Answer (score 1):

It's because of *default user agent stylesheet*. Different browsers set different default CSS rules, so in your example *h1* tag has this style by default:

```
margin-block-start: 0.67em; 
margin-block-end: 0.67em;
```

You can add this css property to your css code and it will fix your issue:

```
#second h1{
    margin:0;
}
```